# Histograms in Levelplot() when Plotting a Raster

Tags: r, plot, levelplot

I have a raster called r. I need to plot it using levelplot() in r. I used the following codes

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

# Define the color ramp
colorRamp <- colorRampPalette(c("orange","pink","yellow","green","dark green", "blue","dark blue"))

# Plot the raster
levelplot(r , col.regions = colorRamp(100), main = "Predicted BD", scales = list(draw = FALSE))
```

These codes generate a map that has two histograms on top and right corner of it as in the following image:

[image]

I do not like those graphs on the top and the right corner of my map, but I do not know how to get rid of them. How can I remove them from my map?

Comment: Reading [`?levelplot`](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis/blob/master/man/levelplot-methods.Rd), there's an argument `margin=`, and it sounds like if you set `margin=FALSE` then the marginal plots will not be included. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `margin = FALSE` will get rid of the maps on the margins of your levelplot.

Comment: The argument "margin = FALSE" was useful and solved the problem. Thanks